# Have two jupyter notebook option, one works but one has "Error Starting Kernel"

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have both python3 and python3.6(tensorflow) notebook option in my Jupyterlab. I can run the python3 notebook and use tensorflow without problem. But when I try to open a file with python3.6(tensorflow) notebook, I always get a "Error Starting Kernel Unhandled error". I am wondering why I would have two options of notebook, how to fix the kernel starting error for python3.6(tensorflow) or how to remove this python3.6(tensorflow) notebook option? I am using a Mac. Many many thanks!

Comment: Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to get the list of kernels.                                       You can delete the kernel via                                                                                                   `jupyter kernelspec uninstall kernel_name`                                                                                           where `kernel_name` is name of the kernel you want to remove. Thanks